# copyWithZone issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nscopying

I am trying to make a copy of my UIViewController subclass by doing:

```
BookViewController *bookVC = [catalogFlatViewController copy];
```

and I have the following error:

```
'-[BookViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e5f00'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS copyWithZone unrecognized selector only when using device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539522/ios-copywithzone-unrecognized-selector-only-when-using-device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIViewController` does not conform to `NSCopying`. If you want to make a copy, you have to use `NSCoding`:

```
NSData *archive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:controller];
UIViewController *newController = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archive];
```

If you've added new ivars to your view controller, you'll have to override the `NSCoding` methods (`encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:`) to serialize and deserialize these correctly. See [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

BTW, this is basically how a nib file works.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to @Caleb answer in the below post:

[iOS copyWithZone unrecognized selector only when using device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539522/ios-copywithzone-unrecognized-selector-only-when-using-device)

**Caleb**'s answer is as under

> UIViewController doesn't implement the NSCopying protocol. Unless
>   you've implemented NSCopying in your own UIViewController subclass,
>   your view controller won't respond to `-copyWithZone:`.

For more information: you may want to refer to [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

But I would suggest you not to implement NSCopying Protocol Reference, as @RobNapier has given one of the very nice and informative article at [Implementing NSCopying (or NSCopyObject() considered harmful)](http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439)

Hope this helps.