# Swapping the values of two variables that point to objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pointers

I have the following problem, because i just have started coding objective-c.

I have some instance with

```
@interface MyClass
    @property (strong) MySecondClass *first;
    @property (strong) MySecondClass *second;
@end

@implementation MyClass
    @synthesize first = _first;
    @synthesize second = _second;

    /*this is called while initialisation*/
    -(void) initialisation{
        _first = [[MySecondClass alloc] init];
        _second = [[MySecondClass alloc] init];
     }

    /*what i want to do*/
    -(void) swap{
        // second one should be replaced with first one
        _second = _first; 

        // first pointer should be replaced by new instance
        _first = [[MySecondClass alloc] init];
    }

@end
```

Problem is, that when i call the swap method, the _first still points to the old object so _second will be replaced by same new object.

I already tried copy like follows, but it throws an exception.

```
 _second = [_first copy];
```

PS: Im using ARC

**Edit**

What i really would like to accomplish, would be something like:

```
 _second = _first
 MySecondClass *tmp = [[MySecondClass alloc] init];
 _first = &tmp;
```

But this shows compiler error:  Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'MySecondClass *' is disallowed with ARC

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of exception is it throwing?  the console should reveal that.

Comment: The exception: 
Uncaught exception: -[MySecondClass copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf305570


I dont't want to copy the memory, just the pointer to it. The _first pointer then should point to a new object.

Comment: I always get this kind of problem and I ended up with writing copyWithZone. There is something called deepcopy ans shallowcopy the reason behind this.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: No, the distinction between deep and shallow copying of objects has nothing to do with swapping the values of two variables.

Comment: @Dom - the first `-(void)swap{` does what you want. It is not clear what your problem is

Comment: @hooleyhoop: No, the original implementation of `swap` does not swap the variables.

Comment: @peterhosey does your answer swap the variables?

Comment: @hooleyhoop: Yup. (Strictly speaking, no, since it's not swapping the existing values, but rather swapping the value from `_first` into `_second` before creating the new object to store into `_first`. A more precise description would be that it pushes a new object into a two-element queue; if there was already a second object, it falls off when the former first becomes the new second. But that's what the questioner asked for.)

Comment: @peterhosey ok, and that is different than the first `-(void)swap{` how?

Comment: @hooleyhoop: I explained the difference in my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What i really would like to accomplish, would be something like:
>
> ```
> _second = _first
> MySecondClass *tmp = [[MySecondClass alloc] init];
> _first = &tmp;
> ```
>
> But this shows compiler error: Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'MySecondClass *' is disallowed with ARC

That's because the values of `_first`, `_second`, and `tmp` are already pointers, so “`&tmp`” is a pointer to a pointer—an “indirect pointer” (not especially clear wording on the compiler authors' part).

The solution there is to not say `&tmp`. You just want `tmp` here.

Comment: I found out that my problem is a little more complex than my simplified example. You are right, my swapping function does what it's supposed to do, but it doesn't solve my complex problem. I need to look deeper into how viewcontrollers work. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

***My newer answer:***

You should also make certain the class you're trying to copy implements the ["`NSCopying`" protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  For example, [UIViewController doesn't implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539522/ios-copywithzone-unrecognized-selector-only-when-using-device) and so it doesn't respond to calls to "copy" or "`copyWithZone`".

Try resetting that pointer a different way than using "`copy`".

***My original answer:***

try referring to the properties via their accessors.

e.g.:

```
self.second = self.first;

self.first = [[MySecondClass alloc] init];
```

etc.

The only place you must work with "`_second`" & "`_first`" directly is in the class init method.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, but it's the same. By the way, i didn't replaced the setters and getters.

Comment: The point is, that i really DON'T want to COPY the INSTANCE. I just want to swap pointers of one INSTANCE. I got so far that the _second pointer points to the INSTANCE, but now i want to replace the _first pointer to a NEW one.